# Deployment Descriptor not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment-descriptor

I am using NetBeans 8.0 for developing my first Java web application and I am unable to find Deployment Descriptor in the project folder. I don't know where it is located.

I searched the web and then it was written that it'll be in WEB-INF folder, but my WEB-INF folder is empty.

Comment: I haven't developed in NetBeans but the `web.xml` should be indeed in `WEB-INF` and if it isn't, then you should add one.

Comment: @Omoro but the mappings, which should be in Deployment Descriptor isn't there when I create my own. Although controller is mapping correctly, but for my own purpose(learning) I need it.

Comment: Try to google or check some tutorials about the descriptor you need for the kind of application you are developing. I am sure you'll find enough material online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else is facing the same problem, there's an option when you make a new project to include, servlets mapping in web.xml, if you tick mark the option, in that case your web.xml shows up the servlets mapping. And web.xml will be found in WEB-INF folder.